# Can the word 'partner' mean 'customer/client'?

Tags: word-usage

My question stems from the fact that the word 'partner' is excessively used in the former USSR countries when referring to or addressing their customers/clients/buyers. Russian-speaking manufacturers/suppliers/providers/sellers etc. very often use 'our partners' in the meaning of 'our customers/clients/buyers' or start letters with 'Dear Partners, ...' - with the same meaning.

It's not so odd as far as Russian is concerned, but is it in English?

Comment: It's a sort of "advertising speak" -- an attempt to convince customers that you are on their side, working for them.

Comment: Yes, sure, I see. Is it quite frequent/acceptable among native English speakers?

Comment: It would not be used in English like that unless there was some **special** situation.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie -- got it.

Comment: Your ***partners*** must "share common goals" with you. That doesn't usually apply with customers / clients, where you're ***selling*** something and they're ***buying*** it. But if one or both parties are "middlemen" (engaged in both buying *and* selling), it's not ridiculous to call them "partners" (if, say, you sell to them, and they then sell your goods on to the end-user).

Comment: Couldn't agree more, FumbleFingers, thank you.

Comment: Are Russian businesses using "partner" where they formerly used "comrade" ?

Comment: Who cares what words Russians use? It's not their native language, so however they use ***partner***, that doesn't "mean" anything to the Anglophone world at large.

Comment: @GEdgar: No, 'comrade' used to be a title similar to _Mr/Ms_ etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's quite possible (and I was assuming) that either OP was referring to the Russian equivalent of "partner," or else "partner" as such has been taken into Russian, perhaps with a slightly different pronunciation, like "pay" for "pie" is Mexican Spanish.  (When that happens, the meaning and usage may branch off a bit.)

Comment: Andrei, I've seen companies, and freelancers, use "partner" as loosely equivalent to *subcontractor*.  But I haven't seen things go as far as what you described.

Comment: @aparente001 - Yes, I see. Something like "we have reliable **partners (=subcontractors)** to help us do the job in case we can't manage it ourselves". Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Anyone with whom you conduct commerce could be called a trading partner. Business relationships are not coerced, they only exist if they are mutually agreeable. If two parties are trading, they must be partners in some way. A business and their customer must have *at minimum* a common goal of engaging in business, otherwise there is no relationship whatsoever in the first place.

Comment: If you are part of a supply chain, you may have a long-term relationship over many years selling the same thing to a single company or a small number of companies. For instance if you sell machine tools to a nearby factory, or raw materials to that factory. "Partner" might be reasonable, although it's not a formal description of the relationship in the way that "supplier" is.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where Partner would be required & cases where it should be avoided & cases where Either can be used.

**(1A) Customers are not your Partners:**
When you go to a shop and buy things, you are a Customer. In case you give your email address to get newsletters, you should be addressed "Customer".

**(1B) Cynical view:**
When the shop wants to make you feel you are a "Part" of the business, it may want to use the word "Partner" [[ this is the "advertising speak", in comment by user Hot Licks ]] In such cases, it may even use words like "Exciting" & "your favorite Item is available" & "your Exclusive membership ID should be renewed" to make you buy more.

**(2) Customer/Buyer is not End-Customer:**
When a Construction Company buys Steel or Cement or Paint, to construct housing for End-Customers, the Seller may think the Construction Company is a Partner who is actually recommending this Brand over other Brands, to the End-Customer. It may send newsletters saying "Dear Partner, thank you for using our Brand in your Construction Activities" & "Dear Partner, let us know your Estimation of the Material requirements for the next year" and this is a valid case.

**(3) Political View:**
It may be that in Communism, all workers are Partners & Comrades in Developing the Country.

**(4) End-Customers are your Partners:**
In Pyramid Schemes or Multi-level Marketing, Customers (who buy the Items) are also Partners (who sell the same Items to the next level) and it is valid to use "Partners" here.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer.

Comment: As for your "political" assumption (3), no, you aren't correct. But let's agree with _FumbleFingers_ and leave Russian to Russians.